# Trying to display top 3 amount from a table using sql query in oracle 11g..column is of varchar type

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Am trying to list top 3 records from atable based on some amount stored in a column `FTE_TMUSD` which is of varchar datatype

below is the query i tried

```
 SELECT  *FROM 
    (
    SELECT * FROM FSE_TM_ENTRY 
    ORDER BY FTE_TMUSD desc
    )
WHERE rownum <= 3
ORDER BY FTE_TMUSD DESC ;
```

o/p i got

`972,9680,963` -->FTE_TMUSD values which are not displayed in desc

I am expecting an o/p which will display the top 3 records of values

Answer (score 0):

That *should* work; inline view is ordered by `FTE_TMUSD` in descending order, and you're selecting values from it.

What *looks suspicious* are values you specified as the result. It appears that `FTE_TMUSD`'s datatype is `VARCHAR2` (ah, yes - it is, you said so). It means that values are sorted as strings, not numbers - and it seems that you expect *numbers*. So, apply `TO_NUMBER` to that column. Note that it'll fail if column contains anything but numbers (for example, if there's a value `972C`).

Also, an alternative to your query might be use of analytic functions, such as `row_number`:

```
with temp as
  (select f.*,
          row_number() over (order by to_number(f.fte_tmusd) desc) rn
   from fse_tm_entry f
  )
select * 
from temp
where rn <= 3;
```